# Refresh Details Pane in Lightning from Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning

I have a visualforce page which is added to the lead pagelayout. When certain criteria are met the visualforce will update the values on the pagelayout.

In classic I force the page to reload after it updates. (using this sneaky hack: https://www.xgeek.net/salesforce/refresh-standard-detail-page-from-visualforce-page-in-iframe/)

However, in lightning I don't want the whole page to reload. Is there anyway to force a refresh of the details section to refresh without reloading the whole html page?

Thanks heaps
Dan

Comment: Have you tried [force:refreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm)?

Comment: Yes. I tried adding $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();

But no luck. Remember this is in a visualforce page. The page does change a value in the record

So on a specific value changing via a Workflow could the standard component refresh?